# robolectric runOnUiThread on a Thread does NOT work

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

runOnUiThread() does not seem to work when being executed within a thread. Anybody knows of a workaround?

Note: I filed a ticket here - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2479

```
import android.app.Activity;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class RunOnUiThreadTest {

    /**
     * Works
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void inside_the_main_thread() throws Exception {
        final Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicBoolean didRun = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                didRun.set(true);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertTrue(didRun.get());
    }

    /**
     * Fails
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void inside_a_new_thread() throws Exception {
        final Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicBoolean didRun = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        didRun.set(true);
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertTrue(didRun.get());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The results to the tests are likely as expected since the second test blocks the UI thread which is required to run the target `Runnable`.

The first test will pass because the whole method is executed synchronously. Since you are already on the UI thread, when calling `activity.runOnUiThread(...)` the `Runnable` will be executed immediately. Since the `latch` is then 0 `latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` returns immediately and the assert is true.

In the second example you start a new thread and call `activity.runOnUiThread(...)` from within it. Since you are not on the UI thread the `Runnable` is posted to a `Handler` on the UI thread to be executed in the future asynchronously. At this point you proceed to call `latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` from the UI thread which means the `Runnable` cannot run during this time since you are blocking the UI thread.

After 20 seconds the thread resumes but the `Runnable` has never had the chance to run so the assert fails since `didRun()` was never set to true.

Below is an updated test that allows the `Runnable` posted using `runOnUiThread()` to run.

```
@Test
public void inside_a_new_thread() throws Exception {
    final Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicBoolean didRun = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    didRun.set(true);
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    // sleep current thread to give the new thread a chance to run and post the runnable
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // This method will cause the runnable to be executed
    Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler();

    // Should immediately return since the runnable has been executed
    latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(didRun.get());
}
```